# How to return EntityCollection as Outparameter custom activity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, workflow, dynamics-crm-2016

```
    [ReferenceTarget("contact")]
    public InOutArgument<EntityReference> PartyList{ get; set; }
```

How can I return/send a list of ActivityParty or a EntityCollection from a custom CodeActivity back to the workflow step?

Inside my `execute` method, when I return an EntityCollection or a List I get a type conversion error.

---

From the responses below - I wanted to add some clarification:
How can I pass any collection back, I see the list is limited - I was looking for a workaround. Since EntityReference was a reference/pointer type

Comment: Plugins & workflows help you to extend the functionality around the execution pipeline. CRM product platform set you a boundary to play around but not beyond the range.

Comment: It’s not equivalent like C# method returning any data type

Comment: Basically if you want to distribute the WF for child records there’s one codeplex (git?) solution available. Search & use if it fits you.. you are not telling what you are trying to achieve after getting Collection :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EntityCollection is not in supported list of Input/Output type of Custom Workflow activities: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327984.aspx)

What you are trying to achieve by getting EntityCollection in WF step, it should be achievable inside WF activity itself.

You are getting conversion error because your output param type is EntityReference.

Comment: Without telling us what you are after, how can we help you to achieve it? :) @transformer

Comment: Sure. I wanted to return a list of emails back to the workflow from my custom activity. Since I never know how many emails ahead of time, my custom activity creates a dynamic list of activity parties and sends it back - I thought I could is pass it on as an `EntityReference` pointer to a list or collection.. neither is working... so I was hoping to get some help with that. Also, what is EntityRefence, a pointer?

Comment: After returning what you want to do?

Comment: take the items and put into a cc or bcc field, for now I have found a workaround, but for the future I want to know - how to return collections?

Comment: Like I already commented in your question, this can be done within your custom workflow activity, because this is impossible for CRM UI workflow to handle and that’s the reason it’s unsupported to return. Another solution could be pre-create plugin on Email to generate the recipients & add them like https://stackoverflow.com/a/44375610

Comment: Return the Emails in semi colon separated format and put them into cc and bcc of the email. This way you will return a string.

Comment: @mzh I tried this and the system in the `To` and `Cc` field did not accept them as an `ActivityParty` object since it was a string

Comment: @transformer what’s the workaround you mentioned in above comment?

Comment: I used an email template, and scheduled the job in the background. I then created a schedule and let it trigger it. This worked - but the user wanted something slightly diff in their custom wf, so I put it there. In short the Dynamics should support returning collections!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use type `EntityCollection` in generic `InOutArgument<T>` properties.

Supported types are:

- Boolean
- DateTime
- Decimal
- Double
- EntityReference
- Int32
- Money
- OptionSetValue
- String

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327984.aspx).

Comment: Hi is there no way to pass an index to the collection or list back as entity reference. If thats the case how do developers return/pass back multiple `activityparties` .. for multiple receiver situations from a `custom workflow plugin`

Comment: @transformer: workflows are not designed to return data or to execute batch processes. Therefore custom `CodeActivity` classes can only return atomic data items. Technically it is possible to make a workflow execute long running tasks, but to make this work the entire process must be wired to a single `CodeActivity` and it will only work in On Premise deployments.